# FFmpeg / libmp3lame crash while converting from .wav to .mp3 with vibrato

Tags: android, ffmpeg, encoder, android-ffmpeg, lame

I have integrated [mobile-ffmpeg-full-gpl:4.3.1.LTS](https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg) library in my android app. And trying to convert .wav file to .mp3 format with [vibrato](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vibrato) option and libmp3lame encoder.

```
ffmpegCommand = "-i input.wav " +
                "-af vibrato=f=4 " +
                "-c:a libmp3lame " +
                "-b:a 96k " +
                "-ac 1 " +
                "-ar 44100 " +
                "-y output.mp3"
```

**FFmpeg Logs:**

```
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg: Loading mobile-ffmpeg.
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg: Loaded mobile-ffmpeg-full-gpl-arm64-v8a-4.3.1-lts-20200125.
a.b.com D/mobile-ffmpeg: Callback thread started.
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg: ffmpeg version git-2020-01-25-fd11dd500
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg:  Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg:   built with Android (5220042 based on r346389c) clang version 8.0.7 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/clang b55f2d4ebfd35bf643d27dbca1bb228957008617) (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm 3c393fe7a7e13b0fba4ac75a01aa683d7a5b11cd) (based on LLVM 8.0.7svn)
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg:   configuration: --cross-prefix=aarch64-linux-android- --sysroot=/files/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot --prefix=/home/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/android-arm64/ffmpeg --pkg-config=/usr/bin/pkg-config --enable-version3 --arch=aarch64 --cpu=armv8-a --cc=aarch64-linux-android21-clang --cxx=aarch64-linux-android21-clang++ --target-os=android --enable-neon --enable-asm --enable-inline-asm --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-jni --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --enable-shared --disable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=v4l2 --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=v4l2 --disable-indev=fbdev --enable-small --disable-openssl --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --enable-lto --disable-neon-clobber-test --disable-programs --disable-postproc --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-static --disable-sndio --disable-schannel --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disa
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg:   libavutil      56. 38.100 / 56. 38.100
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg:   libavcodec     58. 65.102 / 58. 65.102
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg:   libavformat    58. 35.101 / 58. 35.101
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg:   libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg:   libavfilter     7. 70.101 /  7. 70.101
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg:   libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg:   libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
a.b.com W/mobile-ffmpeg: [wav @ 0x7294a86600] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
a.b.com W/mobile-ffmpeg: Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : mono
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg: Input #0, wav, from '/data/user/0/a.b.com/cache/creation/input.wav':
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg:   Duration: 
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg: 00:00:07.15
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg: , bitrate: 
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg: 705 kb/s
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg:     Stream #0:0
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg: : Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg: Stream mapping:
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg:  (pcm_s16le (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg: Output #0, mp3, to '/data/user/0/a.b.com/cache/creation/output.mp3':
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg:   Metadata:
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg:     TSSE            : 
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg: Lavf58.35.101
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg:     Stream #0:0
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg: : Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 96 kb/s
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg:     Metadata:
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg:       encoder         : 
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg: Lavc58.65.102 libmp3lame
a.b.com I/mobile-ffmpeg: --------- beginning of crash
a.b.com A/libc: psymodel.c:576: void calc_energy(const PsyConst_CB2SB_t *, const FLOAT *, FLOAT *, FLOAT *, FLOAT *): assertion "el >= 0" failed
a.b.com A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 25800 (a.b.com), pid 25800 (a.b.com)
```

**Crash:**

```
--------- beginning of crash
 A/libc: psymodel.c:576: void calc_energy(const PsyConst_CB2SB_t *, const FLOAT *, FLOAT *, FLOAT *, FLOAT *): assertion "el >= 0" failed

? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'samsung/star2qltecs/star2qltecs:10/QP1A.190711.020/G965WVLS7DTE1:user/release-keys'
? A/DEBUG: Revision: '14'
? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
? A/DEBUG: Timestamp: 2020-06-29 15:13:17-0400
? A/DEBUG: pid: 1849, tid: 1849, name: a.b.com  >>> a.b.com <<<
? A/DEBUG: uid: 12171
? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'psymodel.c:576: void calc_energy(const PsyConst_CB2SB_t *, const FLOAT *, FLOAT *, FLOAT *, FLOAT *): assertion "el >= 0" failed'
? A/DEBUG:     x0  0000000000000000  x1  0000000000000739  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000007fd65f7bb0
? A/DEBUG:     x4  0000000000000000  x5  0000000000000000  x6  0000000000000000  x7  0000000000000008
? A/DEBUG:     x8  00000000000000f0  x9  7f96d7a39856d151  x10 0000000000000001  x11 0000000000000000
? A/DEBUG:     x12 fffffff0fffffbdf  x13 000000005efa3d4c  x14 001c23c1a79207f5  x15 000079d970d48db2
? A/DEBUG:     x16 00000073e009e8c0  x17 00000073e007afe0  x18 00000073e492c000  x19 0000000000000739
? A/DEBUG:     x20 0000000000000739  x21 00000000ffffffff  x22 0000007fd65fc44c  x23 0000007fd65f8640
? A/DEBUG:     x24 0000007fd65fd120  x25 0000007fd65fd3a8  x26 0000007fd65f8240  x27 0000007fd65f9e40
? A/DEBUG:     x28 00000071f9f60900  x29 0000007fd65f7c50
? A/DEBUG:     sp  0000007fd65f7b90  lr  00000073e002c27c  pc  00000073e002c2a8
? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
? A/DEBUG:       #00 pc 00000000000832a8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+160) (BuildId: 55ce0a7d78144b0290f9746ed1615719)
? A/DEBUG:       #01 pc 00000000000839e8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__assert2+36) (BuildId: 55ce0a7d78144b0290f9746ed1615719)
? A/DEBUG:       #02 pc 0000000000969c60  /data/app/a.b.com-jXqE8oxytEkfSsn6pcdloQ==/lib/arm64/libavcodec.so
```

I referred [link1](https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg/issues/238), [link2](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8399) to understand the problem but could not find a solution.

Comment: Can you share the input?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xxPAzDSTy8kIjcjC_zJ47IN_6jtlze6I?usp=sharing

Please find two sample .wav audio files.

Comment: Doesn't happen here. First packet in input is detected as corrupt, though. Try remuxing the input first: `ffmpeg -i input.wav -c copy out.wav`

Comment: Also, which version of ffmpeg and lame?

Comment: I've added ffmpeg logs, see if it helps. According to https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg/wiki/Versions, mobile-ffmpeg-full-gpl:4.3.1.LTS includes FFmpeg version - v4.3-dev-1944 and lame version - v3.100

Comment: There are many other ffmpeg commands related to audio and video encoders running completely fine. Just "vibrato=f=4" option is not working.

Comment: @Gyan any update on this. I guess that's a bug with FFmpeg library https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg/issues/488